# Copy data of Email in registration to the username not showing in the registration page

Tags: emails, users

I want to copy the value of email to the username, which is not showing in the registration page, but it is showing in the /user/edit page as **Display Name**, which is randomly generated such that my username is my email, giving more flexibility to the user.

Comment: Are you ok with writing your own module or are you looking for already done solution?

Comment: I am a novice sir. So i dont know to write a module.

Comment: In that case I'm sorry because I won't be able to help you.

Comment: What do you mean by "randomly generated such that my username is my email"? If your username is your email address, that is not random.
To clarify, you want to use the email address as the username?

Comment: @Petrroll sir can you just show me direction, what to do.

Comment: @faerysteel Till now I am using Email Registration module, What this module does is that it give access to login with email and change your username as display name, which is uniquely randomly generated by the module. So, I want that the value of email is copied to display name.

Answer (score 1):

The [Email Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/email_registration) module will allow for using the email address as the username.

The [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module will allow the user to create a username, and allow them to login with either the username OR email address.

Email Registration also provides a hook which will allow a custom module to set the account name to whatever you want it to be.  That does require writing a module, however, it doesn't have to be very complicated.

The only thing you would need to include in your module file is the hook.
Example adapted from http://www.grasmash.com/article/using-your-email-address-your-drupal-username#sthash.uZkOo6j6.dpuf

```
<?php
/* 
* Implements hook_email_registration_name().
*/
function grasmash_email_registration_name($edit, $account) {
  return $account->mail;
}
```

Comment: But this is not the solution because there are some drawbacks of using Email Registration module.

Comment: Then you need to provide more information in your question, and will probably have to write a more complex module to accomplish it.